# VS2008 embedded application GetDlgItem()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce

im trying to transport an application for WinCE 5.0 from Microsoft eMbedded Visual C++ to Visual Studio 2008. I created an Dialog application for my SDK-Platform in VS2008. Most things work so far with minor changes. But i still have a problem:
the "old" application uses

```
MainDialog.cpp:

hListBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX);
```

to get the Handle of a ListBox, where data of a stream driver should be displayed. The ListBox handle is declared globally in a Header-file:

```
App.h:

HWND hListBox;
```

In another C++-File this handle is used to write data into that listbox within an own thread via SendMessage():

```
App.cpp:

SendMessage(hListBox, ...);
```

This works well, but in VisualStudio 2008 the function CWND::GetDlgItem() and CWND::SendMessage() are completely different now. Whats is a good way to handle this in VS 2008?

Regards

Comment: They are not different, these member functions just don't include the HWND argument since the CWnd class already knows the handle.  It is very, very unlikely you should be using the CWnd class at all.  It is an MFC class, converting your old app to MFC would be rather a major undertaking.  Do make sure you are not just looking at the wrong MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MFC's `CWND::xyz`, then the handle is a member variable of the CWND derived class and won't be specified. In your example, it looks like you want the base Win32 API version of these functions. Try specifying the default namespace.

For example:

```
::GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX);
```

and

```
::SendMessage(hListBox, ...);
```

Comment: Just to be clear to the OP, 'specifying the default namespace' means 'putting two colons in front of the function call'